# How do I calculate this double integral?

Tags: calculus

I wonder whether I'm choosing the wrong way of calculating this double integral in segment $D$.

The problem is:
$\hskip2.4in$[image: !enter image description here]

$$\iint_D \cfrac{2 dx dy}{(x^2 + y^2) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = ? $$

Radius of the circle is $R$. 
I am trying to do is:
 .$$  \iint_D \cfrac{2 dx dy}{(x^2 + y^2) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 2
\int^{\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}}_{\frac{R}{2}} \bigg(\int^{\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}}_{\frac{R} {2}} \bigg( \cfrac{dy}{(x^2 + y^2) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\bigg ) dx\bigg)  $$ and it is messy. Should it be this way or is there another way to solve the problem?
Can you help me? Am I doing something wrong? What should I do?

Edit: 
My question is a part of a bigger problem from homework it the course Calculus $3$. Eventually I need to calculate path integral formulation on the chord $AB$ of two given functions - path integral of $Pdx+Qdy$. I thought to use Green's Theorem for that. I have done $Q_x-P_y$ and this is the integral I got I have to calculate on segment $D$ and it seems I don't really get how to do it properly.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate double integrals in polar coordinates?  Like many of us, I appreciate your showing your efforts to solve the problem, but it would help us in helping you understand what's going on if we knew a little more about your mathematical background.  It looks like this is a homework problem.  What kind of a course?  How much background do you already have?

Comment: N.B. $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{r^{3/2}}$, if you use polar coordinates. Also, be careful that your limits match the variables of integration... Lastly, I'd suggest posting the original problem, along with your attempt -- it makes it easier to help.

Comment: Hi. it is homework in the course Calculus 3. Evantually i need to caculate path integral formulation of a sum of two given functions on the path AB. I thought to use Green's Theorem for that. So after i have done Qx-Py (Q(x,y) and P(x,y) are the two given functions) Ive got the integral i want to calculate. And I think I dont really get how to do it properly...

Comment: What do you know about polar coordinates?

Comment: Rewriting the equation into polar coordinates would definitely help since $r^2=x^2+y^2$, so you can get rid of that square root!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to compute the integral is to change to the polar coordinates:
$$
x=r\cos\phi,\quad y=r\sin\phi,\quad dxdy= rdrd\phi,
$$
so that:
$$\begin{align}
\iint_D \cfrac{2 dx dy}{(x^2 + y^2) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
&=\iint_D \cfrac{2 rdr d\phi}{r^3}\\
&=2\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} d\phi\int^R_{R\frac{\cos(\pi/12)}{\cos(\phi-\pi/4)}}\frac{dr}{r^2}\\
&=2\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} d\phi\left[-\frac1r\right]^R_{R\frac{\cos(\pi/12)}{\cos(\phi-\pi/4)}}\\
&=2\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} d\phi
\left(\frac{\cos(\phi-\pi/4)}{R\cos(\pi/12)}-\frac1R\right)\\
&=\frac2R\left[\frac{\sin(\phi-\pi/4)}{\cos(\pi/12)}-\phi\right]_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\\
&=\frac4R\left[\tan\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)-\frac\pi{12}\right].
\end{align}
$$